# Azure Web App Url - http (on portal) vs https (works by default)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been using Windows Azure to host some of our internal utility projects using Web App. When I create a new web app say "MyTestApp", the default URL created in portal will be:

> "http://MyTestApp.azurewebsites.net"

Refer Image

[image]

However, when I click this URL, it will not open in browser. To fix it, I have to manually append "s" in the protocol to make it

> "https://MyTestApp.azurewebsites.net".

I understand that by default, Azure secures the *.azurewebsites.net wildcard domain with a single SSL certificate, so the clients can access the app at

> "https://appname.azurewebsites.net"

But I wondering why the portal display the non SSL URL (http). Is there a reason for that?

**Update:**

I tested it with Firefox too (based on suggestion in comments) and tried both hitting URL as well as Browse button. Since the URL is http, on new tab, it just say "waiting for MyTestApp..." and then "waiting for login.microsoft.com...".

[image]

Comment: According to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/, the "Free and shared service plans do not support SSL". I'm assuming they are referring to a custom certificate on a custom domain. I understand how it does support using SSL cert on *.azurewebsites.net, so this shouldn't apply, but based on your image, you are running on Free. Could you change it to Standard to test this out?

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I click this URL, it will not open the WebApp in browser.

If we click the URL and the [Overview] table is fully loaded, then it will work correctly . We also can browse the website via click the [Browse] option.

> why the portal display the non-SSL URL (http)?

This may be the topic about advantage and disadvantage of Http VS Https. Generally, one of the primary blockers for HTTPS adoption is the fact that the HTTPS protocol is slow. Here’s a very informative ServerFault [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/43692/how-much-of-a-performance-hit-for-https-vs-http-for-apache) showing just how big of a slowdown.HTTPS encrypts traffic between us and a server. It is more security than HTTP. And Azure also allow HTTPS access to our WebApp and support to [enforce HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate#step-4-test-https-for-your-custom-domain) on our WebApp.

Comment: None of above in first paragraph works for me. It tries to load URL with http and goes in endless loop. My question is actually related to Azure portal displaying URL without https but deploy site by default SSL enabled.

Comment: Could you please have a try to refresh or try it with a different browser?
The Azure portal default supports http and https and displays the URL with http.

Comment: Tried to refresh in Chrome, does not work. Will try with different browser.

Comment: I deployed a test webapp http://tomtestjob.azurewebsites.net/, it works corretly for me . please have a try check whether it work for you.  And could please have a try to create and deploy a new webapp?

Comment: It does for me too. But in my case the app is connected to Active Directory and that require redirection for login to https://login.microsoftonline.com. I guess since login url is https and application URL coming from Azure portal is not, it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: Could you please supply more info about the "infinite loop"? Does it can redirect to the WebApp or AD authorization failed then hold on the login interface ? Is there any other error message? please have a try to clear the browser cache and cookie or try it with different browser and check the redirect url configured in the AD application.

Comment: I tested it with Firefox too and tried both hitting URL as well as Browse button. Since the URL is http, on new tab, it just say "waiting for MyTestApp..." and then "waiting for login.microsoft.com...". I have captured browser network console window, will attach it to my question.